# use typescript as primary client side language

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find a way to work with javascript in a way that I can use tools like code completion, refactoring and so on. I finally realized that it is not the problem of tools like visual studio or webstorm, but it is related to javascript language (mostly because it is a dynamic language). I found typescript as a good static alternative. But I found good and bad reviews about it.

I want to know is it good for invest on? I mean can I use it as my main client side language or not? Is it a good idea to migrate all of our javascript codes to typescript and try to use all of its language features?

I need an unbiased answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My simple argument in favour of using TypeScript (given that you want the tooling support) is this. If you decide you don't want to use TypeScript at any point in the future, you can delete all the `.ts` files, keep all the `.js` files and carry on with just the JavaScript.

The JavaScript generated by TypeScript isn't a million miles away from the kind of code I would write myself. It isn't scrambled or unreadable.

So you get the benefits of tooling, compile-time checks, early-access to ECMAScript 6 language features, access to features that might not ever make it into ECMASCript (like generics) and you aren't locked-in to TypeScript if you change your mind.

Answer (score 4):

No such thing as an unbiased answer. Typescript is backed by Microsoft in a big way. Microsoft put Anders Hejlsberg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg the creator of C# behind it and his time is *very* valuable, so I don't think it is going to go away anytime soon. In the MS world typescript has become very popular.

And in the non MS-world it is making splashes quickly as well. Webstorm the premier IDE for web development (used by AngularJS team amongst others) has typescript highlighted as the main new feature right now http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/[image]

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. But I saw some people in community that say typescript is built based on ECMA 6 that is not finished. So it can change and there is no clear feature for typescript because it is based on draft version of a standard.

Comment: The syntax for typescript might change if ECMA script 6 proposal for how to define classes etc changes. Even if it does Microsoft has promised to keep it up to date with the latest standard. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#ECMAScript_6_support Mentioned by Anders multiple times